# sudoku algorithm explanation formula

Tags: php, algorithm, math, formula, sudoku

I'm implementing a sudoku solver using human way algorithm. Which have 3 constraint, different number ini row, cell and box.

I googled and I got http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/12/09/sudoku-creatorsolver-with-php/. But I cannot understand how this guy get `floor($cell / 9)` for return_row function or `floor(return_row($cell) / 3) * 3 + floor(return_col($cell) / 3)` for return_block.

I try to figure it out by write down the data in excel and I know there is some pattern like this :

```
[cell] [column]
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6      6
7      7
8      8
9      0
```

But how did he figure it out that the formula was `$cell % 9` ?

I want to know, if I don't know the answer for the formula, how can I calculate that ? How can I determine that formula ? What method should I use?

Thanks

Comment: This does not sound like a programming problem. If anything, one of the math sites may be appropriate: http://stackexchange.com/sites#science

Comment: okay thanks. I will ask again in math site. But actually this question was similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872773/sudoku-box-indices-start-position , but it's not answering my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes from the way the cells are counted, which we could call row-major.

You can see block and cell numbers with their respective row and column numbers on this image :

[image: illustrated]

### rows and columns

The first row (0) contains cells 0 to 8, the second row cells 9 to 17, and so on until row 8, which contains cells 72 to 80.

If you number rows 0 to 8 and columns 0 to 8 as well, we can see that the formula for a cell that corresponds to this numbering is then `cell = 9 * row + col`, which should explain the formulas for get_row and get_col.

When moving right from any cell by one column, you add 1 to the cell count, which means the formula for the cell number looks like `something + col`.

When moving down one row, you add to the cell number the amount of cells per row, which here is 9, so the formula also looks like `9 * row + something`.

Putting those together, you get a formula that is `9 * row + col + offset` : the "+ something"s dependencies is row and col are determined,  but maybe they still contain a constant value.
In our case, the formula gives the numbering we want with offset=0, but if you started numbering from 1 you formula would be `9 * row + col + 1`.

However you do not have to do this reasoning every time. Just now that when you have a rectangle where you count items row by row, the formula for an item's number is **always** `row * row_size + col + number at (0,0)`. This is also how contiguous memory is allocated for double arrays in C, for example, a very common pattern. If you count column by column, then you have  `col * col_size + row + number at (0,0)`

### Blocks

Now blocks are numbered the same way, but there are only 3 rows and columns. You can replace one by one the elements in the get_block formula to understand it : `floor(row / 3) * 3 + floor(col / 3)`

Since there are 3 rows of blocks but 9 of cells, the (cell-)rows 0, 1 and 2 correspond to the first row of blocks, 3 to 5 to the second row of blocks and 6 to 8 to the final and third row of blocks. What we get out of this is that a row of blocks `rb` contains the rows of cells `3 * rb`, `3 * rb +1` and `3 * rb + 2`. The opposite operation is dividing by 3 and flooring, which gets you `rb` for any of the expressions above.

This works exactly the same for the columns.

Thus when replacing in the expression, we now have : `block_row * 3 + block_col`. This I'd exactly the same formula (with 3 instead of 9) than we had for the numbering of cells, and thus gets you the number of the block from its row and column.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Okay now I understand about the block function. But I still confused, about the get_row and get_cell. Whether to make the function just by guessing ? Or there is some math way to solve this kind of pattern (table)?

Comment: can you explain about is_possible_block function ? It's similar with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872773/sudoku-box-indices-start-position but I still confused.

Comment: @john it's pretty different from what this question is about : it is checking whether a number wasn't already written in a row, column or block. Try writing it out on paper and looking it up, and if you still don't get it and it wasn't asked on SO previously you can make a new question about it.

Comment: ok, thanks. I've posted a new question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685094/block-scanning-on-sudoku-solver-explanation