# Block scanning on sudoku solver explanation

Tags: php, algorithm, sudoku

I tried this sudoku solver http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/12/09/sudoku-creatorsolver-with-php/. It works fine.

Also see this spreadsheet to see more detail in calculation : [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OBJ1TbwlDI9uqHWJFqRlhrm3_9mNYGxwIGA1995ZX-A/edit?usp=sharing)

I understand how the row and col scanning. From the board, we know that:

- index = 9*row + col
- row = floor(index/9)
- col = index % 9

And for the block, because it build from 3x3 board so the formula: `block_index = 3*row_block + col_row`. Because per block there are 3 rows and cols, so the formula for `row_block = floor(row/3)` and `col_block = floor(col/3)`. From here we can conclude that:

```
block_index = 3*row_block + col_row
block_index = 3(floor(row/3)) + floor(col/3)
block_index = floor(row/3)*3 + floor(col/3)
```

This could explain for these function :

- return_row
- retun_col
- return_block
- is_possible_row
- is_possible_col

But I cannot understand about `is_possible_block` function. Here is the function:

```
function is_possible_block($number,$block,$sudoku){
    $possible = true;
    for($x = 0;$x <= 8;$x++){
        if($sudoku[floor($block / 3) * 27 + $x % 3 + 9 * floor($x / 3) + 3 * ($block % 3)] == $number){
            $possible = false;
        }
    }
    return $possible;
}
```

What I know about `is_possible_block` function is:

```
floor($block / 3) * 27 + $x % 3 + 9 * floor($x / 3) + 3 * ($block % 3)

= 9row+col
= 9(floor($block/3)*3 + floor($x/3)) + ($x%3 + 3*($block%3))

row = 3row_block+row_x_block
floor($block/3) = row_block
    floor($x/3) = row_x_block

col = 3col_block+col_x_block
```

How `col = 3col_block+col_x_block` , because what I know, the formula should be like this : `col = 3row_block+col`.

I know `col_x_block` mean column position on 0-8 block. And `row_block` mean row position on 0-2 block.

How do you explain this formula? Thanks

**UPDATE**

Now I know. `floor($block/3)*3` and `3*($block%3)` determine top left corner in block. Then `floor($x / 3)` and `$x % 3` moves each cell in the block.

Comment: Explain the algorithm ?

Comment: Explain about the formula. How do we get that formula? I confused about how to reasoning in is_possible_block formula

Answer (score 0):

I use it in c++

```
for(int k = ((x - 1) / 3) * 3 + 1; k < ((x - 1) / 3) * 3 + 4; k++
```

because of "x" is integer "/" operation return int value.

maybe 3(floor($block-1/3)) can help you.

Comment: can you give more detail on your answer? It's 0-based or 1-based sudoku ? And how do we get number 4 here ?

Comment: I definite array [10][10] and validate fro 1 to 9.

Comment: when x=4,5,6 in ((x - 1) / 3) * 3 + 1
return ((x - 1) / 3) return 1, and ((x - 1) / 3) * 3 + 1 return 4

Comment: can you post the rest of your function ? I really confused about your formula. Because you use 1-based sudoku your formula is `for(int k = ((x - 1) / 3) * 3 + 1; k < ((x - 1) / 3) * 3 + 4; k++` and if I convert it to 0-based become like this `for(int k = ((x) / 3) * 3; k < ((x) / 3) * 3 + 3; k++`. But how to use it ? What is k and what is x ? The result should be like this if $block = 0

`x = 0,k = 0;
x = 1,k = 1;
x = 2,k = 2;
x = 3,k = 9;
x = 4,k = 10;
x = 5,k = 11;
x = 6,k = 18;
x = 7,k = 19;
x = 8,k = 20`

Comment: x is the argument of function

Comment: x is the argument of function

for (int k = ((x - 1) / 3) * 3 + 1; k < ((x - 1) / 3) * 3 + 4; k++)
    for (int l = ((y - 1) / 3) * 3 + 1; l < ((y - 1) / 3) * 3 + 4; l++)
    {
     if (!csp[sdk[x][y]][k][l])
      sum_csp[k][l]++;
     csp[sdk[x][y]][k][l] = 1;

    }

it's a part of forward checking that I wanna update csp values in 3*3 Square in sudoku solver. for example take x=5 and y=2 and trace loop

Comment: forget csp array and just trace sdk array